# url.content not loading image javascript and asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have my javascript in my view and I am trying to load an image from my database into an info window for my google maps but the image does not load.

Javascript code in view:

```
 $.get("@Url.Action("GetMarkers","Donator")", function (json, status) {

      //Global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var marker, data;

      //Loop through the json data
       for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
             data = json[i];
             var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude)
             //Creating marker and putting it on the map
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latLng,
                  map: map,
                  title: data.NpoName + ' says Click Me!'
       });

       // Creating a closure to retain the correct data, notice how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
       (function (marker, data) {
             // Attaching a click event to the current marker
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
             var imageUrl = '<%=Url.Content(' + data.VerificationIcon + ')%>';
             infoWindow.setContent('<h3 class="info-window-title">' + data.NpoName + '</h3>' + '<hr />' + '<p>Npo type: ' + data.NpoType + '</p>' + '<p>' + data.VerificationStatus + '<img src="' + imageUrl + '" alt="verification icon" class="verification-icon" />' + '</p>' + '<a href="/Wallet/Wallet/' + @Model.DonatorID + '/' + data.NpoID + '">Click here to donate!</a>');
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
         });

       })(marker, data);
    };
});
```

Code in controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetMarkers()
{
     //Disable lazy loading
     db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

     //Map marker section
     var DynamicMapMarkers = db.tblNpo.Include(zz => zz.tblVerification).Include(xx => xx.tblNpo_Type);

     //Set map marker values
     foreach (var item in DynamicMapMarkers)
     {
         DonatorUserViewModel MapMarkers = new DonatorUserViewModel();

         MapMarkers.NpoID = item.npo_id;
         MapMarkers.NpoName = item.npo_name;
         MapMarkers.NpoType = item.tblNpo_Type.description;
         MapMarkers.VerificationStatus = item.tblVerification.description;
         MapMarkers.VerificationIcon = item.tblVerification.verification_icon;
         MapMarkers.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.longitude);
         MapMarkers.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.latitude);

         MapMarkerList.Add(MapMarkers);
      }

      var json = MapMarkerList;
      return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Main focus area from the code above:

```
var imageUrl = '<%=Url.Content(' + data.VerificationIcon + ')%>';
infoWindow.setContent('<h3 class="info-window-title">' + data.NpoName + '</h3>' + '<hr />' + '<p>Npo type: ' + data.NpoType + '</p>' + '<p>' + data.VerificationStatus + '<img src="' + imageUrl + '" alt="verification icon" class="verification-icon" />' + '</p>' + '<a href="/Wallet/Wallet/' + @Model.DonatorID + '/' + data.NpoID + '">Click here to donate!</a>');
```

The format of the way the image is stored in the database `~/Images/DbImages/verified.png`

I am not sure why the image isn't loading, or how to work around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Problem is, by the time you get image url `data.VerificationIcon` you are at client side and cannot run `Url.Content` there. This helper is intended to run at server.

Comment: I see, is there any other way I could do it?

Comment: The most simple is returning url from server, instead of a relative path depending on `~`.

Comment: yeah i guess so, the only issue is that the server is local, but thanks anyway